# how to enable security for drools guvnor in websphere 6?

Tags: websphere, drools

I had deployed guvnor in websphere 6 and every thing woks except that I don't know how to enable the security for guvnor.

Comment: (and from then on it uses JAAS to work with the container). ????? You want to elaborate on that, only example I ever found was for JBOSS and it's using property files.

Answer (score 1):

If you deploy the war exploded, you can see the components.xml config file allows you to turn it off or on (and from then on it uses JAAS to work with the container).